# Objects I liked in facebook using graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql

1. I want to find which photo, video, status or other objects I liked in facebook.
   Earlier I used fql to search in the like table:

   `SELECT  object_id FROM like WHERE user_id=me() LIMIT 5000`

   But, in facebook api 2.1, fql is no more supported, so I need to use graph api to replace the above fql.
   So, how can I use graph api to get my likes in facebook?
2. And I need to find who posted those objects also. In fql I used:

   `SELECT uid FROM status WHERE status_id IN (SELECT  object_id FROM like WHERE user_id=me()     LIMIT 5000) ORDER BY uid LIMIT 5000`

   I nee Graph api for the above fql also.

Plese help!

Comment: Not all FQL functionality has been ported over to the API yet. (And most likely, not all _will_ be.)

Comment: Thnkx 4 ur comment. Can u plz give any idea how can I use graph api to fetch my lieks?

Answer (score 0):

Just call the endpoint "`<userid>/likes`". This will give you the information. You need the proper permission for it though: "user_likes".